# Show Shipping Price When Selected In Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `Shipping_method` model. A `shipping method` has an attribute `price_in_cents`.

When user is viewing the `cart` form i want them to be able to select which shipping method they want. Which they can.

However. I want the `price_in_cents` to be displayed next to each shipping method. How do i do that?

```
<%= simple_form_for :cart, url: user_carts_path(current_user), method: :post do |f|%>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :product_id, value: product.id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :outfit_id, value: params[:outfit_id] %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :price, value: product.price %>
  <%= f.input :quantity, collection: 1..10, selected: 1 %>
  <%= f.input :size_id, collection: sizes %>
  <%= f.input :shipping_method_id, collection: shipping %>
  <%= f.button :submit, value: "Buy Now" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Try this `<%= f.input :shipping_method_id, collection: shipping, :label_method => lambda { |shipping| "#{shipping.name} | #{shipping.price_in_cents}" } %>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<%= f.input :shipping_method_id, collection: shipping, label_method:
:price_in_cents %>
```